# Angular --prod issue with border-top-left-radius and border-bottom-left-radius

Tags: css, angular

I have an issue with `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius` on a button which seem to work in development build but not in production. When I run `ng serve` I get the expected result:

[image: Development]

If I just run the same project with `ng serve --prod` I get this:

[image: Production]

...with some errors in Developer Tools:

[image]

Apparently, the build system didn't do a good job. Something didn't work as the styles weren't deployed correctly. This is easily reproducible with both Angular 6 and 7.

1. Create a blank app using `ng new test-app`
2. Add a button in app.component.html

   <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-circle">TEST</button>
3. Add CSS to app.component.css

   .rounded-circle {
     border-radius: 50px !important;
     border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
   }
4. I also used Bootstrap but it is no necessary to reproduce this.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's overriden by the class underneath it that's generated in prod mode. [image: this]

Unchecking it in the dev console like I did in the image results in the correct style, but to actually achieve so try replacing your CSS class with this:

```
.rounded-circle { border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px !important }
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. But aren't those two flavors equivalent? And if so, why does one work while the other does not?

Comment: To my knowledge, this is a fairly common angular-cli prod build bug where it changes the style files order in angular-cli.json. [Here's the issue that's still open](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9475). But as to why mine worked and the other didn't is still a mystery to me, like most of CSS.

My guess is that I formulated the `border-radius` property more specifically using all values which is important to use if you want to override the same property that's also using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command `ng serve --prod --build-optimizer=false`. It might fix your issue.